# Принятие ответов для импортированных вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, принятые-ответы

На сколько я понял, начальное наполнение этого сайта взято с какого-то другого QA сайта. Что будет с вопросами, на которые есть ответ, но нет оригинального автора вопроса что бы принять (Accept) его? Есть ли какой-либо механизм принудительного принятия (Accept) ответа на вопрос? Или эти вопросы всегда будут в выдаче фильтра "Без ответа"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Может ли модератор принять ответ на вопрос за автора?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: Хотя этот вопрос задан ранее, он не содержит полного ответа на то, «как сделать, чтобы на вопросе появилась галочка». Поэтому отмечаю дубль в сторону другого ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если заплюсовать ответ для вопроса из категории "Без ответа", то вопрос будет исключён из этой категории.

Это точно такая же проблема, как и на любом другом сайте сети Stack Exchange — некоторые пользователи забывают принимать ответы. Есть и смежные проблемы: выбор принятого ответа не всегда самый удачный, иногда ответы устаревают. Последствия и решения абсолютно такие же: насильное принятие ответов не предусмотрено, но можно заплюсовать ответ.

Comment: Здесь эта проблема обостряется тем что вопросы старые. У них гарантированно не будет авторов.

Comment: @IvanSolntsev Статистика по вопросам без ответа не самая лучшая, но и не катастрофическая...

Comment: @IvanSolntsev: У части старых вопросов авторы имеются. Иногда даже принимают.