# Как считается статистика отвечаемости вопросов на Area 51?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, вопросы, аттестация, неотвеченные-вопросы

На разделе сайта Area 51, [посвященном StackOverflow на русском](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) приводится такая статистика:

> 74% answered
>
> Needs Work – 90% answered is a healthy beta, 80% answered needs some work. In the beta it's especially important that when new visitors ask questions they usually get a good answer.

Как считается эта статистика? Какие вопросы считаются отвеченными?

Для справки: [StackOverflow на португальском на момент выхода из беты имел 85% отвеченных](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese). Предполагаю, что и для нас этот показатель является целевым.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Давайте разберемся, из чего складываются эти 74%. Будем руководствоваться определением «[не]отвеченного вопроса», данным Джеффом Этвудом в статье [OK, Now Define "Answered"](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/).

> - Answered questions have at least one answer with one upvote (or accepted)
> - Unanswered questions have no answers with upvotes (or accepted)

Всего есть [62040 вопроса.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aquestion) Дальше все проценты даются относительно этой суммы.

Из общего числа вопросов, [40355 (65.09%) считаются `isanswered:yes`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ayes)

- Из них [27387 (44.17%) имеют принятые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ayes+hasaccepted%3Ayes)
- [12973 (20.92%) не имеют принятых ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ayes+hasaccepted%3Ano), но имеют вопросы с положительной суммой голосов. [Это делает их отвеченными по критериям SE](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/127/181472).

В категорию [`isanswered:no` попадают 21680 (34.97%) вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano).

- Из них  вообще не имеют ответов:  [`answers:0` 8205 (13.23%)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano+answers%3A0).
- И [13486 (21.75%) имеют ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano+answers%3A1..).

  - В [5408 (8.72%) эти ответы даже приняты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano+answers%3A1..+hasaccepted%3Ayes). Эти ответы обычно имеют 0 или менее голосов в сумме. Похоже, что здесь оператор поиска расходится с определением. То есть эти вопросы — отвеченные, но `isanswered:no`.
  - В оставшихся [8060 (13.00%) вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano+answers%3A1..+hasaccepted%3Ano) нет ни принятых ответов, ни ответов с суммой голосов выше нуля.

Похоже, что подсчет статистики на Area 51 соответствует данному определению. В «отвеченные» вопросы попадают:

1. 44.17% — имеют принятые ответы и ответы с положительной суммой голосов
2. 20.92% — нет принятых ответов, но есть ответы с положительной суммой голосов
3. 8.72% — есть принятый ответ, но ни он, ни другие ответы не имеют положительной суммы голосов.

В сумме – 73.81%, что округляется как раз до 74%.

Встает новый вопрос: как нам повышать этот процент, чтобы выйти из фазы беты и вообще улучшить показатели сайта?

Comment: Пересмотреть те 8060 вопросов и определить, а куда их девать. А то встретится что-нибудь вроде http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/339641 - имхо вообще не по теме, too broad и сверху unclear, однако открыт. Потом просмотреть 13486 - если на ответе висит "спасибо", его можно апнуть и перевести вопрос в категорию "отвеченные". Потом дальше смотреть, что получилось.

Comment: Надо задать еще 38к "правильных" вопросов: с принятым заплюсованным ответом... и других не задавать. притом еще неплохо было бы чтоб ответов в каждом было несколько (лучше больше трех). :-)

Comment: @Vesper я правильно понимаю, что закрытые вопросы в статистике неотвеченных вопросов не участвуют, поэтому имеет смысл закрыть все старые вопросы, которые являются вопросами не по теме?

Comment: @Regent Тут хитрее, закрытые удаляются по времени, если на них нет голосов "за", точнее, сумма голосов за и против 0 или меньше. Да, по-моему имеет смысл так сделать, хотя бы ради того, чтобы балласт кривых вопросов уменьшился. На интерес проверил на enSO то тже запрос, который выдал здесь 8060 - там ответ был внезапно 1100000+ (1160429, или 11.85% от всей базы вопросов)! И там светились [duplicate] и прочее, но с голосами "за".

Comment: @Vesper: проверил. Закрытые с `votes:..0` — удаляются, копии — вечно висят.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что присутствует проблема «древние вопросы с положительным балансом голосов и без ответов закрывать бесполезно — это не улучшит ситуацию»? тогда можно флэшмоб наличными силами устроить: «доведём баланс вот этих вот вопросов до нуля (а лучше до минус одного)!». только нужен запрос, получающий соответствующий список.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: пожалуйста: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano+answers%3A0+votes%3A1..100

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо! ну, значит, можно подумать над формулировкой призыва к флэшмобу. только предварительно надо убедиться, что такая инициатива не будет отрицательно воспринята администрацией или движком.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Если минусовать не «все подряд вопросы из списка», а «просто плохие вопросы» — то какая разница, как мы их нашли? Поиск — это просто инструмент модерации в данном случае.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, согласен. но мнений администрации и движка, увы, не знаю. мнений по поводу призывов и массовых минусований.