# Увеличить лимит закрытия вопросов за день

Tags: предложение, закрытие-вопросов

Связанный вопрос: [Как считается статистика отвечаемости вопросов на Area 51?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/807/181472)

Одна из актуальных задач на сегодня — закрывать старые некачественные вопросы, которые портят статистику и не укладываются в тематику сайта. Закрытый вопрос с голосами ≤0 и старше трех месяцев удаляется системой.

Прежде всего речь идет о вопросах [совсем без ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3Ano%20answers%3A0) или с [ответами, не получившими голосов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3Ano%20answers%3A1..%20hasaccepted%3Ano) — так что мы при этом не рискуем потерять какие–либо ценные ответы.

Для закрытия вопросов используются голоса за закрытие, лимит которых совсем невелик. В чате неоднократно звучали жалобы на то, что «закрывашка кончилась» и предложения ее увеличить.

Фиксирую эти предложения в вопросе на Мете.

Обращаю внимание на то, что в вышеупомянутом множестве вопросов есть не только вопросы, которые заслуживают закрытия. Также там есть:

- Сложные вопросы, на которые хорошо бы дать ответ.
- Вопросы, на которые дан верный/хороший ответ, но этот ответ не был оценен. Если вы видите такой ответ (или комментарий «спасибо, помогло») — поставьте голос «за». Автору будет приятно, а вопрос перейдет в категорию отвеченных.

Поэтому закрывать нужно не все подряд.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: насколько я понимаю, закрытый вопрос с голосами ≤0 и старше трех месяцев удаляется системой. Какие еще есть способы?

Comment: Да, это наилучший из возможных, как мне кажется. Постараюсь завтра с утра обговорить с ребятами возможные варианты с лимитом голосов. Согласно вашему предложению, можно было бы снять лимит на голосования на заданный срок для пользователей с репутацией больше `N` (где `N`, например, 1000).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо, будем ждать.

Answer (score 3):

Данных для обоснования увеличения лимита приведено не достаточно. Статистику "портят" прежде всего новые вопросы ([за последние полгода 62%, а общая статистика (74%) является такой же как у большого SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/875/)). То есть в первую очередь нужны полезные ответы.

[Система старые ненужные вопросы сама удаляет](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/137096).

Comment: Были бы вменяемые вопросы ещё.  А общая статистика на enSO кстати хуже - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/338814/answered-question-percentage-for-the-last-m-months за 12 месяцев 55% отвеченных, если верить этому запросу. Так что логичнее чистить авгиевы конюшки, чем всерьез бороться за ответы в каждом вопросе, хотя и об этом забывать нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Лимит голосов следует поднять *временно*, потому что на данный момент есть много оффтопика и вопросов плохого качества, и при этом мало участников с правом голоса. Со временем, когда качество подрастет и активных участников станет больше, лимит можно вернуть в прежние рамки.

Answer (score 0):

Постоянно вижу сообщение:

> Достигнут дневной лимит голосов за закрытие; пожалуйста, попробуйте
>   еще раз через 6 часов

Я не виноват, что слишком много мусорных вопросов. Просто хочу избавить мир от этого мусора, а система не позволяет =/

Неплохо бы было увеличить лимит, хотя бы до тех пор, пока число активных юзеров увеличится.

Comment: Я думаю, активных участников уже вполне достаточно.

Comment: Дя совсем плохих вопросов - мусорных, рейтинг <=0 (<=1 если не жаль минусануть) - есть тревоги. Их количество раскачивается со временем (до *сотен* в день). И беджи за них дают. Пользуйтесь.