# Некоторые цифры по ru.SO

Tags: обсуждение, аттестация, цифры

- [Quantcast говорит что кол-во посещений ru.SO падает (две цифры за 3 месяца)](https://www.quantcast.com/ru.stackoverflow.com#!traffic).  Не ясно на каком уровне трафик стабилизируется.
  [image: quantcast-traffic-ru.SO-2015-Apr-Jul]
- [Кол-во вопросов в день ~75 в течении последних месяцев](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/338276/questions-per-day-last-6-month#graph), что в ~100 раз меньше большого SO и примерно соответствует относительной посещаемости сайтов
- [всего 128 пользователей создано за последние полгода с репутацией больше 200](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/338810/number-of-users-with-reputation-at-least-n-that-are-created-in-the-last-m-months?minrep=200&months=6). [Area51 рекомендует >150](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian)
- [`1.3` -- отношение кол-ва ответов к общему кол-ву вопросов за последние полгода](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/338811/answer-ratio-for-the-last-m-months?months=6). Area51 рекомендует 2.5
- [74% вопросов получают ответ, одобренный хотя бы одним другим участником](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). Большой SO имеет тот же процент. И только [62% за последние полгода.](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/338814/answered-question-percentage-for-the-last-m-months?months=6) Area51 рекомендует  >80% для бета-сайтов.

---

Вопрос создан из [ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/849/6) участника [@jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs).

---

Ещё пара метрик из [обсуждения на Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261601/137096).

- [Кол-во активных экспертов (более одного одобренного ответа за неделю) от времени](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/341448/number-of-active-experts-per-week#graph):

[image: active experts ru.SO]

- [две трети экспертов осталось с прошлого (2014) года](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/341457/active-experts-100-burnout-rate-after-a-year-by-default?year=2015&week=26&comparisonGap=1.0)

Comment: Что интересно, этот же запрос показывает, что на enSO за шесть месяцев отвеченными оказались всего 55% вопросов, то есть мы выше основного сайта по этому показателю!

Comment: @Vesper: эта цифра ожидаемо должна быть выше у бета-сайтов таких как ru.SO

Comment: Увеличить количество ответов на вопросы можно следующим образом: корифеям, таким как VladD, не отвечать сразу же, а дать шанс другим участникам. Гуру отвечают быстро и практически всегда правильно, так что другим уже нет смысла давать свой ответ. А если им дать шанс, они будут отвечать. Ну а корифеи пусть отвечают выждав денёк, если правильных ответов не будет. Вот только это приведёт к тому, что ru.so наполнится массой неточных ответов. Нужно ли это?

Comment: Мне кажется, такой подход ошибочным. Задающим нужен ответ и как можно быстрее. На мой взгляд, необходимо: 1) больше вопросов на разнообразные тематики, 2) улучшение правил сообщества.

Comment: Поясню про правила. Например, в англоязычном сообществе считается полезным улучшение ответов в стили википедии, то есть если новичок видит 5 хороших ответов, которые дополняют друг друга, то он может создать 6, объединив все 5, добавив результатов тестирования, примеров своего кода и т. д. Для этого, нам, сообществу, надо выработать такие правила и обучать новичков.

Answer (score 9):

К сожалению, мы не можем получить всех необходимых данных на Quantcast в силу ХэшКод-прошлого проекта. Спешу поделиться мыслями относительно статистики ресурса.

**Сезонность профессиональных ресурсов**. У профессионально ориентированных сайтов, таких как Stack Overflow на русском, посещаемость летом и в выходные дни ниже. Тренд на снижение посещаемости начинается в апреле/мае и продолжается до середины августа. Наибольшее количество пользователей приходят на сайт в октябре и марте. Если говорить про дни недели, то наименее популярными днями изучения программирования является суббота и воскресения, а наиболее вторник и среда.

**Запуск нового сообщества**. Stack Overflow на русском был запущен в самом начале апреля 2015 года. Многие русскоязычные разработчик были приятно удивлены и опубликовали новость среди своей аудитории. В результате сайт получил дополнительные 50К сессий, чем получил бы в обычных условиях. Статистика ХэшКода говорит, что средний прирост посещаемости в год составляет от 20% до 30%. В апреле 2014 года Google Analytics зарегистрировал порядка 634К сессий, в 2015 - 924К, что опять же на 79К сессий больше, ожидаемых 845К. Если сравнить данные за июнь 2014 (553К сессий) и 2015 (788К сессий), то прирост составит 42%.

**Ошибки переноса**. Если бы все всегда происходило гладко, возможно, в Stack Overflow не было бы такой сильной необходимости. После перехода на новый движок, Яндекс практически перестал индексировать сайт. (По большому счету, индексацию сайта Яндексом мы сломали еще в середине 2012 года.)

Поясню. По статистике за 2012 год, соотношение поискового трафика в русскоязычном сегменте Интернета выглядело примерно так: 60% переходов шло из Яндекса, 30% из Google и еще 10% делили между собой все оставшиеся поисковики. В 2010 - 2011 годах это утверждение было верно для ХэшКода, но после различных “оптимизаций” движка, трафик из Яндекса упал за один день и больше никогда не возвращался в исходную пропорцию (с тех пор Google отправлял нам в более чем в два раз больше пользователей, чем Яндекс).

Таким образом, давайте взглянем на прирост пользователей из поиска для Яндекса и Google. В июне 2014 года Google отправил на сайт порядка 371К сессий, Яндекс - 151К сессий, то есть разница почти в полтора раза (если быть точным 1.46 раза). За тот же период 2015 года, Google отправил на сайт порядка 672К сессий, Яндекс же лишь 46К, то есть разрыв более чем на порядок (точнее 13.6 раз)!

**Количество вопросов**. Согласно статистики Stack Exchange, за июль 2012 было задано 1.3К вопросов, за июль 2013 года было задано 1.4К вопросов, за июнь 2014 года было задано 1.5К вопросов, за июнь 2015 года было задано *2.5К* вопросов.

В последние несколько месяцев будние дни на Stack Overflow на русском задается от 90 до 130 вопросов, в выходные от 50 до 70.

**Количество ответов**. Согласно статистики Stack Exchange, за июль 2012 было опубликовано 1.7К ответов, за июль 2013 года было опубликовано 1.6К ответов, за июнь 2014 года было опубликовано 1.3К ответов, за июнь 2015 года было опубликовано почти *3К* ответов.

В последние несколько месяцев, в будние дни на Stack Overflow на русском публикуется от 110 до 140 ответов, в выходные от 60 до 80.

**Подводя итог**, можно сказать, что тренд посещаемости на самом деле положительный: прирост в июне по сравнению с предыдущем годом составил 42%, в сравнении с 33% за аналогичный период в предыдущих годах. Количество вопросов и ответов после перехода на новую платформу заметно выросло.

Сообщество Stack Overflow на русском растет как никогда до этого, за что всем нам отдельное спасибо! *Мы - молодцы!*

Comment: А можно ли как-то вернуть индексацию сайта Яндексом? А то глядишь, трафик пойдет, ой-ой-ой какой прирост может быть!

Comment: Я бы очень хотел этого. Ситуация, на самом деле, печальная. Получается, что если через Google люди могут найти решение своей проблемы, то через Яндекс нет. И вполне может быть, что проблема поиска ответов на технических вопросы через Яндекс справедлива и для Stack Overflow на английском. То есть проблема не столько в цифрах, сколько в отсутствие возможности уменьшить время поиска новых знаний по работе.

Comment: Вообще да, я, если мне что-то надо найти, пишу запрос на английском и сразу в гугл, потому что яндекс мне возвращает максимум ссылку на такой же заданный вопрос где-нибудь на ответах-мэйлру, и без ответа, причем даже если вопрос задан на английском, яндекс не посылает меня на stackoverflow. А дальше начинается эффект монополии - если предыдущие ХХХ раз я нашел ответ на enSO, зачем мне искать где-то ещё, пойду и спрошу.

Comment: @Vesper, насколько я знаю, русско-язычные [около-]компьютерщики информацию, связанную с [около-]компьютерной тематикой, предпочитают искать (даже по-русски) не в яндексе, а в гугле. / типа, таков тренд предпочтений.

Comment: июнь-июль намеренно перепутаны в параграфе **«Количество вопросов»**?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Что касается поиска: я использую Duckduckgo, он вполне индексирует оба сайта.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: А нельзя ли поговорить с кем-нибудь из Яндекса? Не думаю, что Яндекс специально не хочет выдавать ссылки на нас. Если вопрос разрешится, то, думаю, к взаимной пользе — нас и Яндекса.

Comment: @VladD Я несколько дней назад написал в их службу поддержки. Жду ответа. Прочитал повторно их документацию. На вид, мы допустили несколько ошибок в роботе, но не уверен, что это могло так сильно повлиять.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Отлично! Если от этих переговоров будет нетривиальный результат, может быть, стоит поделиться со сообществом на мете.

Comment: 100% стоит в любом случае! Как только будет виден прогресс, сразу же опубликую "рецепт", вдруг у кого аналогичная проблема.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky прогресса так и нет?

Comment: @alexolut Вы имеете в виду прогресс с Яндекс.Поиск'ом?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да

Comment: @alexolut Где–то месяца три назад был у них в офисе на дне открытых дверей. Поговорил со всеми, кого смог найти (ответственные за весь поиск, за алгоритм ранжирования, за работу роботов и еще несколько специалистов). Результат: как я понимаю, ошибка на стороне Яндекса Сказать точно в чем именно, я не могу, так как не работаю в Яндексе. Обещали починить. Пока все по–старому.

Comment: @alexolut Ребята о проблеме знают. Это проблема всех сайтов Stack Exchange (включая Stack Overflow на английском).