# Какие метрики стоит использовать для измерения прогресса сообщества?

Tags: обсуждение, статистика, data-explorer

[Цель нашего сообщества](/help/manifesto) — создать мир, в котором на каждый запрос на все прикладные вопросы по программированию к поисковику, в выдаче есть ссылка на развёрнутый ответ на русском языке.

Чтобы желаемый нами мир стал реальностью, мы вместе создаём базу знаний сообщества на русском языке. Путь к такой грандиозной цели непрост и извилист: есть вероятность заблудиться. На мой взгляд, нам нужен ориентир, который поможет не сбиться с верного пути.

> Давайте вместе подумаем, какие метрики могли бы послужить нам ориентиром на пути к нашей цели?

[image]

#### Что следует учесть выбирая метрику?

Мы можем использовать любые доступные данные. Нет нужды ограничиваться существующими метриками сайтов сети Stack Exchange. Хотя мы можем создать сколько угодно любых метрик, хочется отметить:

- *Чем меньше метрик, тем лучше*. Оптимально, если бы мы смогли создать одну метрику для отслеживания всего прогресса. С другой стороны, у системы есть несколько важных аспектов, которые очень сложно измерить в случае комплексного подхода.
- *Метрики должны быть интерпретируемые*. Цель метрик — в простой понятной форме показать участникам, как развивается сообщество: с чем всё хорошо, а где нужно поработать. Чем проще провести ассоциацию численной оценки процесса с необходимым действием для улучшения, тем лучше.
- *Метрики должны быть универсальны*. Хочется иметь возможность посмотреть одну и ту же метрику в разных сообществах, чтобы понять, можно ли делать лучше то, что мы уже делаем.

#### Основные метрики: сообщество, качество, количество

Думая про «единую метрику» создаётся впечатление, что метрик должно быть три:

1. *Сообщество*. Насколько комфортно участникам в сообществе? Хотят ли они принимать участие на сайте (задавать или отвечать на вопросы, голосовать и т.д.)? Хотят ли приглашать коллег? Хотят ли люди присоединиться к нашему сообществу?
2. *Качественная оценка содержимого*. Насколько создаваемые нами знания полезны и интересны участникам сообщества и русскоязычным разработчикам в целом?
3. *Количественная оценка содержимого*. Как быстро пополняется база знаний?

#### Какие метрики видите вы?

Пожалуйста, предложите в ответе к этому вопросу метрики, которые вы хотели бы использовать для отслеживания прогресса? Как эти метрики рассчитать? Какие данные необходимо использовать?

Пожалуйста, размещайте **одну метрику в одном ответе**, чтобы не возникло путаницы в отзывах.

Я постараюсь реализовать лучшие предложенные метрики по каждому из разделов (сообщество, качество, количество) и сделать их доступными всем.

Comment: связанные вопросы [Некоторые цифры по ru.SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/875/23044), [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Comment: You might find this MSE post useful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137975/has-anyone-tried-to-calculate-the-community-health-index-chi-for-any-stack-exc (Простите за английский)

Comment: @rene Большое спасибо за ссылку!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky какие-нибудь итоги/выводы? (:

Comment: @Suvitruf Планирую еще подождать какое–то время и потом проанализирую отзывы на всех международных сайтах разом.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а результаты планируете опубликовать на MSE или на каждой отдельной мете?

Comment: @Suvitruf Все зависит от результатов анализа. Мне лично очень хочется на MSE про международные сайты писать чаще. Будет возможность, обязательно там напишу.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky просто тема эта, как по мне, актуальна для всех сообществ, а не только для локализованных)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky к чему в итоге пришли? )

Answer (score 15):

Число пользователей, задавших 1 вопрос и больше никогда не появляющихся на сайте. Общий тренд и по месяцам.

Answer (score 6):

Метрика "Насколько SO лоялен по отношению к заслуженным участникам" в первую очередь предназначена для сравнения с другими сайтами сети. Надо выявить, действительно ли ruSO "особенный", или это общесистемное явление. Действительно ли есть проблема в *качестве* отношения к участникам сообщества.

Количество участников из топ 100, которые совершили менее 5 постов (вопросов, ответов. Комментарии и очереди проверки не считаем) за месяц. Обязательно с учетом удаленных и заблокированных.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky 1 - любое решение должно перед собой иметь какую-то проблему, которую оно решает. Решение без проблемы - бесполезно. 2 - я не могу составить адекватной метрики ни на одну из запрошенных в вопросе категорий, т.к. они СЛИШКОМ обширны и расплывчаты. Очень сложно загнать в 3 цифры все показатели здоровья SO. 3 - поэтому я беру маленькую часть, называю её тезисом и предлагаю метрику для его проверки и мониторинга.

Comment: Проблема: у нас есть цель — создание базы знаний сообщества. Вопрос в том, чтобы мы могли в любой момент времени посмотреть каковы наши успехи в этом начинании по сравнению с прошлой неделей, месяцем, годом.

Answer (score 5):

Соотношение общего числа вопросов к числу вопросов, на которые получен ответ. По месяцам.

Comment: Общее число вопросов меняется со временем: обсуждалось, что многие вопросы не выживают и через некоторое время удаляются духом. Допустим, сейчас январь 2020 года, по состоянию на 1 февраля в январе будет 100 тысяч вопросов, а по состоянияю на 1 марта в январе останется только 90 тысяч.

Comment: @AK с учётом этого нюанса )

Comment: Просто любой ответ?

Comment: @avp можно две метрики. 1) Принятый ответ. 2) Хотя бы 1 ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Тезис - сайт заполоняется учетками однодневками, которые делаются для задания одного низкокачественного вопроса "на удачу". Какую-никакую реакция вопрос получает (и даже ответ, от сердобольных участников). После этого учетка выкидывается или откладывается.

Предлагаю метрика для определения количества таких учеток (1), и метрику для наблюдения за приходом действительно новых участников (2).

1. Количество вопросов от участников с репутацией менее 30, которые задали не более 2 вопросов и не проявляли активности на сайте более 2 недель с тех пор. Обязательно учитывать удаленные вопросы.
2. Аналогично, но с репутацией более 30, которые задали более 2 вопросов за неделю и проявляли активность на сайте.

Answer (score 3):

***Сообщество***

Количество заблокированных учетных записей за единицу времени, разбитое по причинам блокировки.

В статистику желательно включить участников, для которых [заблокирована возможность задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) из-за количественных ограничений платформы.

Эта информация, насколько я понимаю, недоступна через SEDE, т.ч. размещение на мете будет единственной возможностью для обычных участников оценить масштабы проблем сообщества. И, разумеется, было бы интересно сравнить статистику блокировок у нас с другими сайтами сети.

Вообще, в целях прозрачности, можно было бы публиковать полные списки блокировок. Это даже не будет нарушением конфиденциальности, ведь эти же данные итак публикуются в профиле заблокированного участника. Полный список позволил бы точечно рассмотреть наиболее проблемные части сообщества.

Тем не менее, если полная публикация по каким-то причинам невозможна, то, уверен, даже в обезличенной статистике найдется пища для размышлений.

Comment: Список блокировок я считаю обязательно нужно, потому что я видел нескольких пользователей с высокой репутацией, забаненных на огромный срок непонятно за что. При наличии такого списка можно будет судить о том, насколько наказания соответствуют тяжести проступков.

Answer (score 3):

Так как

> на все прикладные вопросы по программированию к поисковику, в выдаче есть ссылка на развёрнутый ответ на русском языке

— наша цель, то мне кажется если мы хотим придти к одному показателю, то нам не нужно учитывать степень комфорта участников в сообществе. Этот показатель можно отнести к другой цели: Всем участникам должно быть комфортно.

Если брать во внимание только первую цель, то есть такая идея:

Для каждой метки(не учитывая общие: алгоритм, массивы и тд) количество запросов в Яндексе(https://wordstat.yandex.ru) за определённый период делим на количество вопросов с этой же меткой с правельным ответом за тот же период.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень интересная идея!

Answer (score 1):

Число новых участников, преодолевших порог в 300 репутации, чтобы знать, сколько к нам приходит активных участников, способных давать хорошие ответы.

Comment: Новый участник -- уточните, сколько дней он считается новым? А нужно ли учитывать  перерывы в его деятельности (тут, конечно, появляется вопрос, что считать перерывом) и выбрасывать их?

Comment: @avp я имею в виду тех, кто просто преодолел этот порог. Формулировка наверно неточная просто получилась.

Comment: @avp а вот сколько плашка "новый участник" показывается, столько и считается.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev тогда наверно порог в 300 будет высоковат

Answer (score -10):

Лучшая метрика, не использовать метрику. Ибо использование метрики показывает только "однобокий" взгляд . И ориентируясь на цифры в метриках общество загонит себя только в "проценты роста". Тобишь по метрикам всё станет только лучше, в то время как в реальности только хуже и хуже ;_;.

**пир во время чумы.**

*Олигархи(старожилы) будут видеть в метриках "динамику роста" (аля коля %5 ), в то время  как ситезены "рабы западного типа" будут разбегаться под гнётом новых правил и обрядов. прям как `стаковер флов без приставки ру`*

---

Если уж метрик не избежать то предлагаю, метрику "социального дружелюбия " те кто даёт комментарии и не ставит минусы .

Comment: Спасибо! Не могли бы вы пояснить, пожалуйста. Я понял далеко не все.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky то почему я не нахожусь на stackoverflow там меня по сути забанили :3 . А почему такой ответ просто он не стандартный , мы привыкли что хаем свою историю и свою и культуру . А я решил использовать методику от пративного наоборот и хаять их систему которую везде нам насаживают.