# Показатель отвечаемости

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, неотвеченные-вопросы

Существует ли показатель отвечаемости в движке stackoverflow? Если stackoverflow собирает статистику отвечаемости, где её можно посмотреть и какая она сейчас?

Понятно, что такая программная статистика будет далекой от реального положения и не учитывать нюансы. Например, разделять отвечаемость на сложные и простые вопросы - объективно невозможно. Может быть кто-то проводил аналитику?

Comment: См. [общий список сайтов SE](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions)

Comment: В принципе тут есть страничка (но я вечно ее теряю) где можно задавать SQL-запросы к базе SO.

Comment: Вот я как раз это то же хотел написать. Есть API (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=default&site=ru.stackoverflow&run=true) и есть еще доступ к SQL, но я то же не помню где :)

Comment: @Mike, http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: связанные вопросы: [Как считается статистика отвечаемости вопросов на Area 51?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/807/23044) и [Статистика отвеченных вопросов и актуальные задачи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1339/23044)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Общая статистика доступна на [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday). Дополнительную информацию можно наблюдать через инструменты модерации, которые доступны участникам с 10k+ репутации на соответствующей [странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools). Об этом есть информация на [странице привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). При репутации 25k+ появляется [ещё больше способов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) получения статистики по сайту.